# Breaking spokes very often at J bend

Tags: wheels, spokes

I have a urban commuter bike. Since last couple of months, the spokes at the rear wheel keep breaking after each ride. I changed the broken spokes couple of times. Also I replaced all the spokes. Same thing keeps happening. I weigh around 90 Kg. I have had the bike for 2 years and covered only 6000 Km. I check the spokes before going for a ride. Almost never have I found a loose spoke and yet after the ride I find one broken. Should I replace the whole wheel or just the rim/hub? Is my weight the problem here?

Edit- 1) Being a complete amateur in the field, I didn't know what details mattered. The wheel is Double walled 36H with double cross lacing (Both sided).(This is an assumption. I am attaching photographs to make things clear.)
2) I didn't change the spokes myself. I had it done from a shop.
3) I go over the curb or rather potholes  (We have a lot of those here in India) moderately hard. 
[image: Hub]

[image: Wheel]

Comment: How many spokes on the  wheel?  How is it laced?  Disk brakes?

Comment: I don't think your weight is the issue necessarily because i weight about the same as you if not a bit more and am not regularly breaking spokes. More information would be helpful such as spoke type, number of spokes, lacing type etc.

Comment: Is it a cheap [BSO](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/887#887) from a discount department store, or did it come from a bicycle shop?  Do you bomb over curbs and railroad tracks, or do you go over gently?  Please edit your original question to answer.

Comment: Please tell us what the brand and model of the bike is.  You say you replaced spokes, did you do that yourself or have a repair shop do it?

Comment: Is your bike a lightweight track bike?   A clear, clean and well-lit photo of the bike might clarify a lot of things.

Comment: @Criggie OP said their bike is an urban commuter

Comment: Those look like steel flange hubs. They are thinner and harder than aluminum, which puts more stress on the spokes. Better spokes might help, but the real solution would be better wheels.

Comment: That is 3-cross spoke lacing (or even 4-cross -- can't tell for sure).  You count the cross right at the hub.

Comment: As @ojs says, the flanges are too thin and likely poorly rounded at the holes.  And the steel cuts into the spokes.  You need a new wheel with an aluminum hub.

Comment: There are special little washers, with a rounded edge on opening on one side, that can be used to fix this situation, but that would require rebuilding the wheel, and it is probably cheaper (and better) to just buy a new wheel.

Comment: @ Daniel R Hicks Thanks Daniel. I appreciate your help. I am gonna buy a new wheel with aluminum hub. I just hope they have it here.
@ojs Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It is usually a sign that the spokes are free to move axially at the hub. which will stress the J bend. That's one of the reasons better wheels use straight spokes. You may be able to find rather cheap ones of that kind although they might still cost more than a BSO-ish bike.

Comment: @Carel - I strongly recommend avoiding straight spokes.  They are probably fine when they come from the factory, but any adjustment is incredibly difficult and apt to cause damage.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks: I have 4 sets of wheels with straight bladed spokes and never had a problem with a spoke in the past eight years. One rear wheel got slightly out of true once which was easily fixed.You just have to keep the spoke from twisting with a slotted holder when working on the nipple.

Comment: @Carel - "Just" have to keep it from twisting, eh?  Easier said than done.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks : Mavic wheels are delivered with a pair identical tools: a tyre lever, a nipple wrench, a spoke holder and a bearing adjustment tool. If you do not have such a tool, a block of hardwood in which you cut a narrow slit with a small hacksaw serves the same purpose quite well.

Comment: @Carel - Flat spokes, maybe.  Round straight spokes are the Devil's work.

Comment: Alright,people! I tried everything mentioned here. The problem still persisted. Unwilling to waste anymore more, I have decided to buy a new proper road bike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normal. A properly built wheel with quality spokes will not break spokes like this. The likely culprits are build quality (spokes over-stressed?) of spokes quality. Take your wheel to a bike mechanic and ask if the spokes tension looks right and if the cross-pattern is OK. If it does, then you are left with poor quality spokes; change them.